# How to convert a string to a ifstream

Tags: c++, ifstream

i am trying to open a file with ifstream and i want to use a string as the path (my program makes a string path). it will compile but it stays blank.

```
string path = NameOfTheFile; // it would be something close to "c:\file\textfile.txt"
string line;

ifstream myfile (path); // will compile but wont do anything.
// ifstream myfile ("c:\\file\\textfile.txt"); // This works but i can't change it
if (myfile.is_open())
{
   while (! myfile.eof() )
   {
      getline (myfile,line);
      cout << line << endl;
   }
}
```

I am using windows 7, My compiler is VC++ 2010.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string path = compute_file_path();
ifstream myfile (path.c_str());
if (!myfile) {
  // open failed, handle that
}
else for (string line; getline(myfile, line);) {
  use(line);
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to work, the same thing happens. All i get is a blank myfile.

Comment: @bob: What do you mean by that?  You are using an *input* stream, so myfile must already contain data you want to read.

Comment: nurk, what? I am trying to use getline to output all of the text out of the txt file. It works fine if i set the name of the ifstream before but then i can't change the name.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried `ifstream myfile(path.c_str());`?

See a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790219/read-from-file-variance-calculation/4790718#4790718) about the problems with `while (!whatever.eof())`.

Comment: !eof() is a perennial problem. :(

Comment: @Fred Nurk: Does that mean from now on it'll only arise once a year instead of three times a week? :-)

Comment: Yes i did try that, that was my 2nd thing i did before i posted.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure as to how this actually compiles, but I assume you are looking for:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
//...
//...
std::string filename("somefile.txt");
std::ifstream somefile(filename.c_str());
if (somefile.is_open())
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Same problem the somefile is blank.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Check out piece of code working for me 
//---------------------------------------
char lBuffer[100];
//---
std::string myfile = "/var/log/mylog.log";
std::ifstream log_file (myfile.str());
//---
log_file.getline(lBuffer,80);
//---
```